# How to set WebSocket write timeout in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, websocket

I am using Tomcat 9 and Spring.

My web application has a websocket service.

My application sends binary messages to client using `sendMessage` of:

`org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession`.

According to Tomcat documentation,

> the write timeout used when sending WebSocket messages in blocking
>   mode defaults to 20000 milliseconds (20 seconds). This may be changed
>   by setting the property
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT in the user
>   properties collection attached to the WebSocket session

.

How to set `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT` value from Spring? I don't see how to get Tomcat session from Spring session.